# php global excution inside the class

Tags: php

PHP's `define("CONSTANT", "Hello world.");` is global function which is you can call it even if your inside the class or function. I have example below and let's say inside the class I declare a global variable supposed to be like private global `$allForm`;

my question how can i call the $this->allForm inside validate() without embedding the $this->validate() inside the __construct?

```
$authentication = new authentication("1", "nanat", "amew", "yes" ); // declared define constant

class authentication extends mySession {
    private $allForm; //variable

    public function __construct($submit, $user, $password, $remmeber) {
        $this->allForm = array('giSub' => $submit, 'giUser' => $user, 'giPas' => $password, 'giRemmeb' => $remmeber); //execute
       // $this->validate(); //not execute
   // $this->validateOne(); //not execute
   // $this->validateTwo() //not execute
    }

    private function validate() {
        var_dump($this->allForm); // return null
        // statement...
    }

private function validateOne() {
        var_dump($this->allForm); // return null
        // statement...
    }

private function validateTwo() {
        var_dump($this->allForm); // return null
        // statement...
    }


}
```

what i want is.. is this possible?

```
class authentication extends mySession {
    private $allForm; //global variable.. 


    public function __construct($submit, $user, $password, $remmeber) {
        $this->allForm = array('giSub' => $submit, 'giUser' => $user, 'giPas' => $password, 'giRemmeb' => $remmeber); //execute
    }

    private function validate() {
        var_dump($this->allForm); // return true
        // statement...
    }

private function validateOne() {
        var_dump($this->allForm); // return true
        // statement...
    }

private function validateTwo() {
        var_dump($this->allForm); // return true
        // statement...
    }


}
```

Comment: Sorry, what? Could you try to explain that by example?

Comment: What would achieve by doing that? You have encapsulated your code in a class making use of the private `$allForm`. Excellent.

Comment: is there a way you can set a global variable with out calling the $this->validate();? in order to execute the $this->allForm? imaging you have the 5 function then you will include the all function inside the __construct in order to execute the this->allForm?

Comment: What do you mean by "executing `$this->allForm`"? `authentication::$allForm` is a *variable*, it can't be *executed*. There are also no constants whatsoever in your code. Based on these misnomers, I suspect your use of the word "global" may also mean something else.

Comment: i mean you cant call $this->allForm inside the validate() with out executing $this->validate() inside the  __construct; example:  public function __construct($submit, $user, $password, $remmeber){
  $this->allForm = array('giSub' => $submit, 'giUser' => $user, 'giPas' => $password, 'giRemmeb' => $remmeber); //execute
    //$this->validate();
 }

private function validate(){
          var_dump($this->allForm); //return null
         ..statement} }

Comment: I don't understand what and why you need to it... do you know debug_backtrace? maybe you can do something with it...

Comment: You absolutely can *access* (not "call", or "execute") $this->allForm from inside validate().  Of course, if you're not calling validate() inside the constructor, you'll need to call it from some other method of your class (since it's private).

Comment: Since your `validate()` method is `private`, it can only be called from other methods inside your `authentication` class. Since the only other method in your class is `__construct`, that's the only place you can possibly call it from. So... the answer is no?

Comment: Other than your code comments, both snippets are identical and I still can't figure out what you're asking

Answer (score 2):

You aren't required to immediately call `$this->validate()` from the construct. If you're populating `$this->allForm` in the constructor, the value will continue to exist when you call class methods. Remove that `$this->validate()` from `__construct()` and you can call the `validate()` method manually:

```
$authentication = new authentication( "1", "nanat", "amew", "yes" );
$authentication->validate();
```

Based on the way you have asked this question, that's the best answer I can provide.

Comment: +1 for attempt at answering this. Note that you'd need to mark the `validate` method as `public` to do what you suggest.

Comment: is there a function just like php difine.. inside the class? can be a global variable and can access of all froms function? without binding each another?

Comment: @mapet Sorry, your questions just don't make sense. Could you update your question with code that demonstrates what you *would like to do*? The code doesn't need to work, it should just show the result you'd like to achieve.

Comment: @deceze Ah, I missed that. My mistake, thanks for pointing out the error.

Answer (score 1):

`$allForm` is declared as a `private` member of `class authentication`.  This means that you can only access `$allForm` from code that is *inside* `class authentication`.  If you want to access `$allForm` from *outside* the class, you'll need to declare it as `public`.

You can apply the same reasoning to the `validate()` method as well. If you want to be able to call it from *outside* the class, then just declare it `public`:

```
class authentication extends mySession {
    public $allForm;

    ...

    public function validate() {
       ...
    }
}
```

Now you can do stuff like this....

```
$authentication  = new authentication("1", "nanat", "amew","yes" );
$authentication->validate();
```

OR

```
$authentication->allForm = array(....);
```